# JHipster Gulp Build Error: Unexpected "space" found

Tags: jhipster

The application is running fine on development profile. When I run the production build there is an error: [JHipster Gulp Build] Error: Unexpected "space" found. I look out for this error on google and it is a CSS error but I have a lot of CSS files and to find it is a hard task.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of work looking for the solution, this is clearly a CSS error, but as I use many third-party libraries in my case, finding it is like looking for a needle in a haystack, so my solution was to go to the file: "gulp/build.js "and comment on line 39:

```
.pipe (plumber ({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
```

This line catch the exceptions and hide it, then I commented it to see exactly where the exception is being launched and this was in the file:

"node_modules/postcss-elector-arser/dist/processor.js" and on line 29 where the error starts with a very generic message. I simply added to the error message the variable "selectors" that has the selectors to be analyzed:

original:

```
Line 29: launch new Error (e);
```

Updated by:

```
Line 29: launch new error (e + "in selectors:" + selectors);
```

Using this, it is possible to see which CSS selectors have the error and correct it.

This was my solution to solve the problem, I hope it helps others because, for me, it was a waste of 2 days of hard work.

Comment: Do you think using csslint would have helped?

Comment: Maybe, I did not test it, but believe me, I tried anything even using QAPlug (QAPlug is an Intellij IDEA plugin to manage code quality which integrates tools such as PMD, Checkstyle and Findbugs.) And it is a hard work.